# Dynamic php submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a php form with dynamic checkboxes. It must connect to sql server and get their count and names. At the end I want submit the checked boxes.

example
I get from db some vegetables, for a receipt, and  add checkboxes in my form. The user will check some of the and submit it.

I can't make `<input type=checkbox id=...>` because when post it i will not know the names of them. For that reason, i made a js function and when a checkbox checked, i add it to a array.

Now i want ask you, how i can submit this array and after that get the values at post.php file?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I can't. Its complicated with th names. For that reason i post only description. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your checkboxes like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="veg[]" value="tomato">
<input type="checkbox" name="veg[]" value="lettuce">
<input type="checkbox" name="veg[]" value="carrot">
<input type="checkbox" name="veg[]" value="celery">
```

Even if you don't know the names, you can iterate through the checkbox using:

```
<?PHP
    foreach($_POST["veg"] as $veg){
        echo $veg;
    }
?>
```

Comment: It sound good. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added name attributes to your checkboxes? Like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="potatoes" />
```

Comment: yes. Names from sql select